# Click multiple divs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a method I can use in jquery to click all of these div elements at once instead of using the javascript method below.

```
document.getElementById('Div_Remove_1').click();
document.getElementById('Div_Remove_2').click();
document.getElementById('Div_Remove_3').click();
document.getElementById('Div_Remove_4').click();
```

Comment: Assign them all a class, then use `$(".remove").click();`

Comment: you can use a loop to loop through all the ids

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is called [start-with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$('[id^="Div_Remove_"]').click(function() {
  // you code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. With jQuery**

```js
(function($) {
  // Assign handlers
  $('button').click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
  });
  
  // Click all
  $('button').trigger('click');
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button-1">button 1</button>
<button id="button-2">button 1</button>
<button id="button-3">button 1</button>
<button id="button-4">button 1</button>
```

**2. Without jQuery**

You can use a loop to do it. like this snippet:

```js
// Select all buttons
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="button"]');

// Assign handlers
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = clickHandler;
}

// Handler function
function clickHandler(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
}

// Trigger handlers
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].click();
}
```

```html
<button id="button-1">button 1</button>
<button id="button-2">button 2</button>
<button id="button-3">button 3</button>
<button id="button-4">button 4</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a click event for more than one selector in a row with jQuery:

```js
 $('div').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
 });
 
 $('#Div_Remove_1, #Div_Remove_2, #Div_Remove_3, #Div_Remove_4').trigger('click');
```

```css
div { width: 100px; height: 80px; background: black; margin-bottom: 10px; }
div.clicked { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Div_Remove_1"></div>
<div id="Div_Remove_2"></div>
<div id="Div_Remove_3"></div>
<div id="Div_Remove_4"></div>
```

Anyway if you are able to add a class to those divs, you will easily do whatever with all of them, eg. `$('.mydivs').trigger('click');`